# React - Redux How to filter the global state when redirecting to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React app in which a global state is setted by using redux, in one component a Form is filled and based on the inputs I do an axios request to the same endpoint from where redux fetch the data then I want to redirect to another component and filter the state based on this new request. The problem is that when I am redirected the same state that redux defined is shown and no the updated one.

My redux logic is this:

actionsCreator **productActions.js**

```
import { fetchProductsStart, fetchProductsSuccess, fetchProductsFailure } from '../slices/productsSlice';
import { baseUrl } from '../../shared/baseUrl';

export const fetchProducts = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    dispatch(fetchProductsStart());
    const response = await fetch(baseUrl+"products");
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch(fetchProductsSuccess(data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(fetchProductsFailure(error));
  }
};
```

the slice reducer is **productsSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


const productsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
  },
  reducers: {
    fetchProductsStart(state) {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    fetchProductsSuccess(state, action) {
      state.products = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
    },
    fetchProductsFailure(state, action) {
      state.error = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
    }
  }
});

export const { fetchProductsStart, fetchProductsSuccess, fetchProductsFailure } = productsSlice.actions;

export default productsSlice.reducer;
```

and my store **configureStore.js**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import productsReducer from "./slices/productsSlice"
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    products: productsReducer
  }
})
```

the logic in the form that I mentioned above in the handleSubmit is:

```
    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()

        // redirect to the store component with the search criteria
        // the search criteria will be passed as query parameters
        var tipo  = this.state.tipo
        var marca = toTitleCase(this.state.marca)
        var linea = this.state.linea
        axios.get(baseUrl+'products' + '/?tipo=' + tipo + '&marca=' + marca + '&linea=' + linea )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('response.data',response.data)

            // here I am using the useNavigate hook to redirect and set the state
            // with the response that is returned with the axios request
            this.props.navigate("/store",{
                state:{
                    products:response.data
                }
            });
     
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    
    }
```

How could I correctly update my state in order to filter this based on the inputs gotten from the form inputs? Is there a better way to do this I am kinda newbie with redux I can´t figure how to update the state.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the component from where I am redirecting is a class component and I can´t change it to functional one

**EDIT2:** I just could change the logic so now the component from where I am redirecting is a functional Component